# Find adapter for an air hose

Tags: valve, pump, hose, compressor, air-compressor

I bought this adapter to easier fill my car tires with air:
[image]
(https://ebay.us/vtTY9x)

However, the outer diameter of the left side is 1/4" and it has no inner thread.

I wanted the left side to be a schrader valve so I can connect it to electric bike pump.

How do I convert the left side to a schrader valve?

Comment: I think the only answer is to find an adapter that will connect to those 1/4" threads - are you looking for some other answer?  Also, this seems off topic for this site.

Comment: It sounds like what you really wanted is a valve stem extension -- male schrader valve on one end, female connector for schrader on the other end.

Comment: I was thinking a valve stem and a hose clamp also Greg+

Comment: 1/4" Shrader fittings are common, you can get one at MSC for a couple of bucks. A better bet is your local auto parts shop, which is more convenient.